# Snakemake "Function did not return str or list of str."

Tags: python, function, input, wildcard, snakemake

I'm trying to run a RNAseq snakemake pipeline. I'm getting stuck on my input function.

```
import pandas as pd
import os
import fnmatch
import re
 
# --- Importing Configuration Files --- #
configfile: "/DATA/config/config.yaml"
 
table_cols = ['dataset','sample','species','frr','gtf_version','fa_version']
table_samples = pd.read_table('/DATA/config/samples.tsv', header=0, sep='\t', names=table_cols)
DATASET = table_samples.dataset.values.tolist()
SAMPLE = table_samples['sample'].values.tolist()
SPECIES = table_samples.species.values.tolist()
FRR = table_samples.frr.values.tolist()
GTF_VERSION = table_samples.gtf_version.values.tolist()
FA_VERSION = table_samples.fa_version.values.tolist()
 
print(DATASET,SAMPLE,SPECIES,FRR,GTF_VERSION,FA_VERSION)
 
 
rule all:
        input:
                directory(expand(config["project_path"]+"resources/starIndex_{species}_{fa_version}_{gtf_version}",zip, species=SPECIES, fa_version=FA_VERSION, gtf_version=GTF_VERSION)),
                expand(config["project_path"]+"results/{dataset}/star_aligned_1pass/{sample}_{species}_Aligned.sortedByCoord.out.bam", zip, dataset=DATASET, sample=SAMPLE, species=SPECIES)
                
wildcard_constraints:
        dataset="|".join([re.escape(x) for x in DATASET]),
        sample="|".join([re.escape(x) for x in SAMPLE]),
        species="|".join([re.escape(x) for x in SPECIES]),
        gtf_version="|".join([re.escape(x) for x in GTF_VERSION]),
        fa_version="|".join([re.escape(x) for x in FA_VERSION])
 
 
## rule starIndex ##  Create star index if it does not exist yet
rule starIndex:
        priority: 1
        input:
                fasta=expand(config["project_path"]+"resources/{species}.{fa_version}.dna.primary_assembly.fa",zip, species=SPECIES, fa_version=FA_VERSION),
                gtf=expand(config["project_path"]+"resources/{species}.{gtf_version}.gtf",zip, species=SPECIES, gtf_version=GTF_VERSION)
        output:
                directory(config["project_path"]+"resources/starIndex_{species}_{fa_version}_{gtf_version}")
        threads:
                20
        params:
                directory(config["project_path"]+"resources/starIndex_{species}_{fa_version}_{gtf_version}")
        conda:
                "envs/DTPedia_bulkRNAseq.yaml"
        shell:
                """
                STAR --runThreadN {threads} --runMode genomeGenerate --genomeDir {output} --genomeFastaFiles {input.fasta} --sjdbGTFfile {input.gtf}
                """
 
rule star_1pass_alignment:
        priority: 4
        input:
                read1=config["project_path"]+"resources/raw_datasets/{dataset}/{sample}_{species}_RNA-Seq_1.fastq.gz",
                read2=config["project_path"]+"resources/raw_datasets/{dataset}/{sample}_{species}_RNA-Seq_2.fastq.gz",
                index=determine_species,
                prefix=config["project_path"]+"results/{dataset}/star_aligned_1pass/{sample}_{species}_"
        output:
                bam=config["project_path"]+"results/{dataset}/star_aligned_1pass/{sample}_{species}_Aligned.sortedByCoord.out.bam",
                log=config["project_path"]+"results/{dataset}/star_aligned_1pass/{sample}_{species}_Log.final.out",
                sj_1pass=config["project_path"]+"results/{dataset}/star_aligned_1pass/{sample}_{species}_SJ.out.tab"
        threads:
                12
        conda:
                "envs/DTPedia_bulkRNAseq.yaml"
        shell:
                """
                STAR --runMode alignReads --genomeDir {input.index} --genomeLoad LoadAndKeep --outSAMtype BAM SortedByCoordinate --limitBAMsortRAM 10000000000 --limitGenomeGenerateRAM 20000000000 --readFilesIn {input.read1} {input.read2} --runThreadN {threads} --readFilesCommand gunzip -c --outFileNamePrefix {input.prefix}
                """
```

This is the error:

```
['PRJNA493818_GSE120639_SRP162872', 'PRJNA493818_GSE120639_SRP162872', 'PRJNA362883_GSE93946_SRP097621', 'PRJNA362883_GSE93946_SRP097621'] ['SRR7942395_GSM3406786_sAML_Control_1', 'SRR7942395_GSM3406786_sAML_Control_1', 'SRR5195524_GSM2465521_KrasT_45649_NoDox', 'SRR5195524_GSM2465521_KrasT_45649_NoDox'] ['Homo_sapiens', 'Homo_sapiens', 'Mus_musculus', 'Mus_musculus'] [1, 2, 1, 2] ['GRCh38.106', 'GRCh38.106', 'GRCm39.107', 'GRCm39.107'] ['GRCh38', 'GRCh38', 'GRCm39', 'GRCm39']

Building DAG of jobs...
WorkflowError in line 113 of /DATA/workflow/snakefileV21:
Function did not return str or list of str.
```

I for example tried modifying the line after return without success and the same error output:

```
# function determine_species_fasta # function for determining fasta input of correct species to rule starIndex
def determine_species(wildcards):
        read1 = config["project_path"]+"resources/raw_datasets/{wildcards.dataset}/{wildcards.sample}_{wildcards.species}_RNA-Seq_1.fastq.gz"
        if fnmatch.fnmatch(read1, '*Homo_sapiens*'):
                return "/DATA/resources/starIndex_Homo_sapiens_GRCh38_GRCh38.106"
        elif fnmatch.fnmatch(read1, '*Mus_musculus*'):
                return "/DATA/resources/starIndex_Mus_musculus_GRCm39_GRCm39.107"
```

Perhaps the wildcards in `read1 = config["project_path"]+"resources/raw_datasets/{wildcards.dataset}/{wildcards.sample}_{wildcards.species}_RNA-Seq_1.fastq.gz"` are not properly filled in? I also tried `unpack()` without succes https://snakemake.readthedocs.io/en/v6.0.0/snakefiles/rules.html#input-functions-and-unpack.

I hope you could help (:

**EDIT 1**

I've changed the code to this after suggestions from @SultanOrazbayev. This snakemake pipeline analyzes RNAseq data from mice and humans. This python input function determines which *species' starIndex* to use and pastes the relevant *directory (not file)* that was outputted in the `rule starIndex`.:

```
# function determine_species_fasta # function for determining fasta input of correct species to rule starIndex
def determine_species(wildcards):
        read1 = config["project_path"]+"resources/raw_datasets/{wildcards.dataset}/{wildcards.sample}_{wildcards.species}_RNA-Seq_1.fastq.gz"
        if fnmatch.fnmatch(read1, '*Homo_sapiens*'):
                return "/DATA/resources/starIndex_Homo_sapiens_GRCh38_GRCh38.106"
        elif fnmatch.fnmatch(read1, '*Mus_musculus*'):
                return "/DATA/resources/starIndex_Mus_musculus_GRCm39_GRCm39.107"
        else:
                raise ValueError(f"Wildcards do not match the desired pattern: {wildcards}")
```

now give this error:

```
(base) @darwin:/DATA/workflow$ snakemake -s snakefileV21 --use-conda 
['PRJNA493818_GSE120639_SRP162872', 'PRJNA493818_GSE120639_SRP162872', 'PRJNA362883_GSE93946_SRP097621', 'PRJNA362883_GSE93946_SRP097621'] ['SRR7942395_GSM3406786_sAML_Control_1', 'SRR7942395_GSM3406786_sAML_Control_1', 'SRR5195524_GSM2465521_KrasT_45649_NoDox', 'SRR5195524_GSM2465521_KrasT_45649_NoDox'] ['Homo_sapiens', 'Homo_sapiens', 'Mus_musculus', 'Mus_musculus'] [1, 2, 1, 2] ['GRCh38.106', 'GRCh38.106', 'GRCm39.107', 'GRCm39.107'] ['GRCh38', 'GRCh38', 'GRCm39', 'GRCm39']

Building DAG of jobs...
InputFunctionException in line 115 of /DATA/workflow/snakefileV21:
ValueError: Wildcards do not match the desired pattern: PRJNA493818_GSE120639_SRP162872 SRR7942395_GSM3406786_sAML_Control_1 Homo_sapiens
Wildcards:
dataset=PRJNA493818_GSE120639_SRP162872
sample=SRR7942395_GSM3406786_sAML_Control_1
species=Homo_sapiens
```

So I suspect this line is not properly executed `read1 = config["project_path"]+"resources/raw_datasets/{wildcards.dataset}/{wildcards.sample}_{wildcards.species}_RNA-Seq_1.fastq.gz"`
Any suggestions to correct this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are not formatting the string you concatenate to the config value

```
# function determine_species_fasta # function for determining fasta input of correct species to rule starIndex
def determine_species(wildcards):
        read1 = config["project_path"]+f"resources/raw_datasets/{wildcards.dataset}/{wildcards.sample}_{wildcards.species}_RNA-Seq_1.fastq.gz"
                                     # ^ was missing this f!
        if fnmatch.fnmatch(read1, '*Homo_sapiens*'):
                return "/DATA/resources/starIndex_Homo_sapiens_GRCh38_GRCh38.106"
        elif fnmatch.fnmatch(read1, '*Mus_musculus*'):
                return "/DATA/resources/starIndex_Mus_musculus_GRCm39_GRCm39.107"
        else:
                raise ValueError(f"Wildcards do not match the desired pattern: {wildcards}")
```

However, this function could be simplified by directly considering the `wildcards.species` value:

```
# function determine_species_fasta # function for determining fasta input of correct species to rule starIndex
def determine_species(wildcards):
    if wildcards.species == 'Homo_spaiens':
        return "/DATA/resources/starIndex_Homo_sapiens_GRCh38_GRCh38.106"
    if wildcards.species == 'Mus_musculus':
        return "/DATA/resources/starIndex_Mus_musculus_GRCm39_GRCm39.107"
    raise ValueError("")
```

If you have problems with your functions, the easiest way to debug is add in some print statements to ensure variables look how you expect.

Answer (score 1):

A mechanical problem with the current function is that the conditions do not capture all cases:

```py
def test(x):
   if x>10:
      ...
   elif x>5:
      ...
   # will return None for x<=5
```

I don't know what the function `determine_species` should return in your case, but perhaps this will work:

```py
def determine_species(wildcards):
   read1 = ...
   if fnmatch.fnmatch(read1, '*Homo_sapiens*'):
      return ...
    elif fnmatch.fnmatch(read1, '*Mus_musculus*'):
      return ...
    else:
      raise ValueError(f"Wildcards do not match the desired pattern: {wildcards}")
```

This will err on cases that do not conform to your `fnmatch` condition.

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion. It shows where the problem is, but doesn't solve the problem.

Comment: Knowing where the problem is usually helps with a solution.